# How do you collect performance metrics from Chrome DevTools Protocol (cdp) with the python selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I have an existing set of frontend automated tests that run in python and use pytest. I would like to add an automated test that, when run against a chromium based browser, collect performance metrics.

Assume that `browser` is a custom wrapper around `RemoteWebdriver` and that I am not able to create a `Chrome` driver inside these tests.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.chrome_only
def test_lighthouse_performance(browser):
    session = browser.bidi_connection()
    # What do I do now?
```

The example [at seleniumHQ](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/#collect-performance-metrics) mentions `aysnc`, but that isn't compatible with my current test framework and  those methods don't exist on the `RemoteWebdriver` class.

In addition, there isn't any documentation on using the [`bidi_connection()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L1030) method is the remote webdriver. The [bidi_api doc page](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/) is similarly unhelpful.

Comment: I think only ChromeDriver implements BiDi or CDP.   Async would only apply to javascript Selenium code methinks.  Though the CDP and BiDi calls are socks so you could make async calls there...

Comment: The test, in my case, will only be run with Chrome. However, it is done through RemoteDriver (BiDi only) because the test suite as a whole is run on multiple browsers

Comment: I guess we'd need to see more code to understand... but RemoteDriver is the sort of super-class for ChromeDriver/GeckoDriver, etc... it implements WebDriver, so all can be typed to WebDriver.  Not sure that Selenium is really the best tool for performance metrics.  You might consider a load tester for something that, and/or building those checks into client-side/server-side code.

Comment: @pcalkins I ended up solving this question. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this out, but it was a lot of trial and error because the CDP documentation is not very user-friendly on the python side of selenium.

This answer will break down the resources I used to get a working solution, examples of code I pulled from, and end with an annotated snippet of code that encapsulates the solution.

- Documentation

  - [Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP)](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/)
  - [Selenium BiDirectional functionality](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/)
  - Pyest plugin for trio: [pytest-trio](https://github.com/python-trio/pytest-trio)
- Useful code resources

  - [Python Remote Webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L1030)
  - [Python CDP implementation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/bidi/cdp.py)
  - [Puppeteer TypeScript implementation of CDP](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/src/common/util.ts#L581)
- Code snippet

  ```
  import pytest

  # These imports are not strictly necessary, but they help with
  #  autocompletion/typing in VSCode
  import selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver as RemoteWebdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.bidi.cdp import CdpSession
  import selenium.webdriver.common.devtools.v113 as v113Devtools

  # The devtools is versioned, you can find the latest version here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/common/devtools/chromium

  import trio  # Selenium uses trio instead of asyncio


  @pytest.mark.trio  # pytest requires this to run the test with trio
  async def test_cdp(browser: RemoteWebdriver):  # See imports above for typing
      page = SomePageObject(
          browser
      )  # This is a page object I made up, you can use your own (or not)

      async with browser.bidi_connection() as connection:
          session: CdpSession = connection.session
          devtools: v113Devtools = connection.devtools

          data = {"traceEvents": []}
          trace_config = (
              devtools.tracing.TraceConfig()
          )  # See documentation links for info on this class

          # Report events is the default transfer mode, but I'm including it here for clarity
          #     There is also a "ReturnAsStream" mode, but unpacking the stream handler it returns
          #     is beyond the scope of this example (and I don't know how to do it yet)
          await session.execute(
              devtools.tracing.start(
                  transfer_mode="ReportEvents", trace_config=trace_config
              )
          )

          # it's important to start the tracing and THEN navigate to the page
          page.navigate()

          session.execute(
              devtools.tracing.end()
          )  # This is the only way to stop the tracing and start the event processing

          async for dc_event in session.listen(
              devtools.tracing.DataCollected, devtools.tracing.TracingComplete
          ):
              # The DataCollected event is sent for each batch of events, and the TracingComplete event is sent when the tracing is done
              if type(dc_event) == devtools.tracing.DataCollected:
                  data[
                      "traceEvents"
                  ] += (
                      dc_event.value
                  )  # Collect the events and do whatever you want with them
              if type(dc_event) == devtools.tracing.TracingComplete:
                  break  # This is how you stop the event loop

          # Do whatever you want with the data at this point
  ```
- Notes

  - You can use the [CDP protocol monitor](https://developer.chrome.com/en/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#protocol-monitor) to find how the devtools configures all of these calls and to find out which events (if you need different ones than I've given an example of here) you should be looking for.
  - If you're willing/able to use a node-cli as part of your testing process, Lighthouse (chrome performance benchmarking tool that utilizes a lot of the same CDP metrics) is available as a [node-cli](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse).